# How to convert upper case to lowercase stored in a variable inside switch statment

Tags: javascript, web

This is my javascript code which is supposed to show: `Okay! Great choice  We are working hard for your cake` if I enter `cak`e or `Cake` (notice c with capital) but working nice with `cake` but not with `Cake` and same goes with `pancake` and capital p `Pancake`:

```
var make=prompt("Hey! What you are up to cake or pancake?");
switch(make){
    case ("cake" || "Cake"):
    console.log("Okay! Great choice  We are working hard for your cake");
    break;
    case ("pancake" || "Pancake"):
        console.log("Okay! Great choice   We are working hard for your pancake");
    break;
    default:
    console.log("Sorry we Only have cake or pancake to choose from.");
}
```

Comment: The logical OR returns its first operand which can be evaluated as truthy, hence you're cases are always the same, non-capitalized versions only.

Comment: Could you please explain what your issues are and what steps you've taken in trying to solve them.

Comment: Note that you can use `make.toLowerCase()` and only check for "cake" as well if you don't want to use fallthrough

Comment: Yap it as i type Cake(c with capital one) it display me Sorry we Only have cake or pancake to choose from.but it suppose to display Okay! Great choice  We are working hard for your cake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `"cake" || "Cake"` evaluates to true, because both those strings are *truthy*. So when user's input is compared with that value, for example `"cake" == true`, it evaluates to true because the user's input (`"cake"`) is also truthy.

To ignore the case of user's input, you can simply convert it to lowercase (by `make.toLowerCase()`) before comparing:

```js
var make = prompt("Hey! What you are up to cake or pancake?");
switch (make.toLowerCase()) {
  case "cake":
    console.log("Okay! Great choice  We are working hard for your cake");
    break;
  case "pancake":
    console.log("Okay! Great choice   We are working hard for your pancake");
    break;
  default:
    console.log("Sorry we Only have cake or pancake to choose from.");
}
```

If you are not familiar with the concept of *truthy* or *falsy* values, you can read MDN's documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/falsy

Comment: `ToUppercase` is always prefered, please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1308-normalize-strings-to-uppercase?view=vs-2015

Answer (score 0):

The `||` operator evaluates as the left hand side if the left hand side is a true value, otherwise it evaluates as the right hand side.

So `"cake" || "Cake"`, because `"cake"` is a true value, means `"cake"`.

Thus `case ("cake" || "Cake"):` means `case ("cake"):`.

---

If you want to have multiple matches in a switch, have multiple cases.

```
case ("cake"):
case ("Cake"):
    // etc
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Invariant comparison:

```js
var make = prompt("Hey! What you are up to cake or pancake?");

if (make.localeCompare("cake".toUpperCase()) == -1) {
  console.log("Okay! Great choice  We are working hard for your cake");
} else if (make.localeCompare("pancake".toUpperCase()) == -1) {
  console.log("Okay! Great choice   We are working hard for your pancake");
} else {
  console.log("Sorry we Only have cake or pancake to choose from.");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, had an issue, it works now.